# Error when starting up my rails server : 767: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Somewhere in my code an error now exists and I cant boot my server properly. Please help

DEPRECATION WARNING: Single arity template handlers are deprecated. Template handlers must
now accept two parameters, the view object and the source for the view object.
Change:

> > Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler.call(template)
> >     To:
> >     Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler.call(template, source)
> >      (called from  at C:/Users/User/Desktop/RubyTutorials/testdev/config/application.rb:9)
> >     => Booting Puma
> >     => Rails 6.0.0 application starting in development
> >     => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
> >     Exiting
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >             46: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
> >             45: from bin/rails:4:in`require'
> >             44: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
> >             43: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in`invoke'
> >             42: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
> >             41: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in`dispatch'
> >             40: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
> >             39: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in`run'
> >             38: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
> >             37: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in`tap'
> >             36: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
> >             35: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in`start'
> >             34: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
> >             33: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in`wrapped_app'
> >             32: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
> >             31: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in`build_app_and_options_from_config'
> >             30: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
> >             29: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`new_from_string'
> >             28: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
> >             27: from config.ru:in`'
> >             26: from config.ru:in `new'
> >             25: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`initialize'
> >             24: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
> >             23: from config.ru:3:in`block in '
> >             22: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
> >             21: from C:/Users/User/Desktop/RubyTutorials/testdev/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
> >             20: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
> >             19: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in`run_initializers'
> >             18: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
> >             17: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in`tsort_each'
> >             16: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
> >             15: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in`call'
> >             14: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
> >             13: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in`block in each_strongly_connected_component'
> >             12: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
> >             11: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in`block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
> >             10: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
> >              9: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in`block in run_initializers'
> >              8: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
> >              7: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in`instance_exec'
> >              6: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Engine>'
> >              5: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker.rb:27:in`bootstrap'
> >              4: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:14:in `bootstrap'
> >              3: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in`refresh'
> >              2: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:84:in `load'
> >              1: from C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in`parse'
> >     C:/RailsInstaller_2_2_5/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 767: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)